# Screen Recording through Macro (VBA) in Microsoft Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I want to perform the following activities in Microsoft PowerPoint through a VBA Macro. I am fine to use the macro either by using Excel or by using Direct Powerpoint. I am using Microsoft PowerPoint 2013.

1. Click on the "Record screen" functionality.
2. Mark the screen area.
3. Click on the slide show and present three or four slides.
4. Then stop recording.
5. Finally your file will be there in your current slide.
6. Save that file with .mp4 format in some local folder.

Can any one help me, please.

I tried exploring various Powerpoint objects, but no luck.

Can any one throw some light on how to access Screen Recording functionality through VBA code?

Comment: Im confused by your question and your tags, question seems to be about PowerPoint but your tags suggest you want to do this from Excel?

Comment: Thanks for pointing, Included the powerpoint in tag. However I am fine with if it is possible to access this through Excel macro.

Comment: First of all this has nothing to do with Excel. Second is I think this isn't possible at all.

Comment: I wrote an excel macro to open a ppt file (name of that PPT file is specified in an Excel cell) and run that slide show along with TTS excel command to speak the notes from that ppt. I did so to avoid editing the original ppt. I know where you are coming from about Excel relationship.to Powerpoint. However as per my requirement, there is something that can be done using excel macro as well. Secondly, I also explored a lot, came to the same conclusion; similar to yours. But we never know, there could be people who makes impossible to possible. and may wanted to help others..

Comment: As there is nothing on this on the web, I'd take a good look at Ppt object and I don't really see anything that seems to be about that functionality... The only thing *"close"* would be `Presentation.CreateVideo` but I'm really pessimistic about what you are asking! :/ Maybe check with [tag:.net]...
Or try to install the updates from this, maybe you'll have something new : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Record-your-screen-in-PowerPoint-0b4c3f65-534c-4cf1-9c59-402b6e9d79d0#OfficeVersion=2013

Comment: @R3uK, I have already explored this link. I could get this done with a little manual intervension. However I want to get this done fully through code (VBA code). Any way thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @R3uK, anyway, your suggestion of Presentation (up voted). CreateVideo helped me to some extend. However, I still wants this to be done through code. I managed to get all these steps done using Win32 API, except for the step2.